# How to label a barplot on the opposite side of a bar of -ve and +ve values with ggplot?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

May I please seek your help to Label a barplot with ggplot2 like the following graph:

[image]

I am using the following code to obtain the attached plot:

```
library(ggplot2)

test <- data.frame(x = c("Moderately Poor", "Deeply Poor", "Deeply & Intensely Poor", "Intensely Poor", "Overall Poverty"), y = c(0.024, -0.046, -0.025, -0.037, -0.083))

test$colour <- ifelse(test$y < 0, "firebrick1", "steelblue")
test$hjust <- ifelse(test$y > 0, 1.03, -0.03)

ggplot(test, aes(x, y, label = x, hjust = hjust)) + 
    geom_text(aes(y = 0, colour = colour)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(fill = colour))

last_plot() + coord_flip() + labs(x = "", y = "") +
    scale_x_discrete(breaks = NA) + theme_bw() +
    opts(legend.position = "none")
```

I was just wondering how can I get the second numeric label on each bar?

Thanks,

Comment: Does [**this**](http://learnr.wordpress.com/2009/06/01/ggplot2-positioning-of-barplot-category-labels/) help?

Comment: or [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11938293/how-to-label-a-barplot-bar-with-positive-and-negative-bars-with-ggplot2)

Comment: @Arun is it possible to add the another label on each bar reflecting the value?

Comment: sorry, I don't quite follow. You mean 2 text labels per bar?

Comment: @Arun, yes. I meant the second numeric label on a bar as reflected in updated plot above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

R graphics, including `ggplot2`, are pen-on-paper, i.e `layers` (each `geom_...`) will be drawn in order.

So, if you want to have a `geom_text` on top of a `geom_bar`, the `geom_text` will need to come after the `geom_bar`.

Updating for `ggplot2` 0.9.3 (the current version)

```
ggplot(test, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_text(aes(y = 0, colour = colour, hjust =hjust, label = x), size=4.5) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(fill = colour)) + 
  geom_text(colour ='black', 
     aes(label = paste( formatC( round(y*100, 2 ), format='f', digits=2 ),'%'),
         hjust = ifelse(y>0,1,0))) +
  coord_flip() + labs(x = "", y = "") +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = NULL) + theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

produces

[image]