# R ggplot reverse axes and control direction of bars

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I am trying to mimic two types of plots (two images provided) where the negative values are to the right and positive to the left. I have sample-code below:

[image]

```
tdf<-data.frame(prcnt=c(-50,25,-80,5,10,-40),nm=c('AB','BC','CD','DE','EF','FG'),catg=c(rep('catA',2),rep('catB',2),rep('catC',2)))
ggplot(tdf,aes(nm,prcnt,fill=catg))+geom_col()+scale_y_continuous(limits=c(-100,100))+coord_flip()+scale_y_reverse()
```

---

How can I also have it mean-centered (at 0) like this? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11938293/how-to-label-a-barplot-bar-with-positive-and-negative-bars-with-ggplot2

Comment: Just use `scale_y_reverse(limits=c(100,-100))` and leave out `scale_y_continuous()`

Comment: thanks for the suggestions, do you know of a way to get the bars to go in the same direction as in the first example plot (image)? Using your code will get it to look like the bottom image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could get the top plot with something like

```
ggplot(tdf,aes(ymin=as.numeric(nm)-.45,ymax=as.numeric(nm)+.45,
               xmin=100, xmax=prcnt,fill=catg))+
  geom_rect() + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=as.numeric(tdf$nm),
                    labels=levels(tdf$nm))+
  scale_x_reverse(limits=c(100, -100))
```

[image]

and you can get the bottom plot with

```
ggplot(tdf,aes(nm,prcnt,fill=catg))+
  geom_col()+
  scale_y_reverse(limits=c(100,-100))+
  coord_flip()
```

[image]