# Conditionally assign geom_text placement for bar charts with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am having an issue when making bar charts with mixed sign values in `ggplot2`. Take the following example:

```
df <- data.frame(year = letters[1:2],
                 value = c(1, -1))

ggplot(df, aes(year, value)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(aes(label = value), vjust = 0.0, size = 5)
```

Which yields:

[image]

I would like to be consistent with the placement of the text - either below or on top of the bars. This is tricky because in both cases in the graph above, the text is directly above the value. However, because the first value is positive and the second value is negative the text appears in a different location relative to the bar. What I would like to see is (adjustments in red):

[image]

My question is: Is it possible to conditionally format label placement based on the sign of the value?

Comment: And then use that other column as `y` in the `geom_text` `aes`thetics. Otherwise use an `ifelse` in the `vjust`. Very similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11939678/3498910)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df <- data.frame(year = letters[1:3],
                 value = c(1, -1,-5)) %>%
    mutate(text_location = ifelse(value < 0,0,value))

ggplot(df, aes(year, value)) +
    geom_col() +
    geom_text(aes(y = text_location,label = value), vjust = 0.0, size = 5)
```

[image]